# How can I access my elements in my dynamic form using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, dynamic

im really sorry i dont know how to acces this one:
Im trying to have a button that when click, computes the total amount from an element which is an array since it is dynamic but accessing methods dont work.

Here is my javascript for adding and deleting:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;

        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;
            case "checkbox":
                newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                break;
            case "select-one":
                newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
    try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                if(rowCount <= 1) {
                    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }
        }
    }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

and then i have this dynamic adding of items:

```
<tr>                            
    <td>Items</td>
    <td style="text-align:left;">
        <INPUT type="button" value="Add New Item" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
        <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Item" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
        <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" >
            <TR>
                <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></TD>
                <TD>
                    <select name="ItemNo[]" id="select" value="ItemNo"  >
                        <?php         
                          $sql2="select * from jewelry_system.item where NumStored !='0' order by ItemName asc";
                          $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
                                              while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
                        ?>  
                        <option value="<?php echo $row2['ItemNo']?>:<?php echo $row2['SalePrice']?>"> <?php echo $row2['ItemName'];?>   [ Php <?php echo $row2['SalePrice'];?> Stocks Left:<?php echo $row2['NumStored'];?> ]</option>                                                          <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE >           
    </td>                                           
</tr>
```

and by using this function to seperate my ItemNo value andthe Sale Priceof the item and then myfunction wont work of adding up that is checktotal():

```
function findexts(f){
    f=strtolower(f);
    exts=split('[/\\:]', f);
    n=count(exts)-1;
    exts=exts[n];
    return exts;
} 
function checkTotal(){
    var total = 0;
    var temp = 0;
    var itemArray = document.trans.ItemNo;

    for(var i=0;i<itemArray.length;i++){
        temp = findexts(itemArray[i].value);
        total += temp; 
    }   
    alert("Total Payment: "+total); 
}
```

Can someone spare timeplease.I really need this. thank youu

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkTotal()
{
    var total = 0;
    var parts = null;

    // Your select input has an ID of "select", so this will iterate through each option
    $('#select option').each( function () {
        // The Item # and Sale Price are separated by a colon (:)
        parts = $(this).val().split(':');

        // Increment the total with the Sale Price of each item
        total += parseFloat(parts[1]);
    });

    alert("Total Payment: "+total);
}
//also The item $ will iterate so try this 
// The Item #,$ and Sale Price are separated by a colon (:)
        parts = $(this).val().split(':');

        // Increment the total with the Sale Price of each item
        total += parseFloat(parts[1]);
    });

    alert("Total Payment: "+total);
}
```

Comment: so is my access method ok?
this part:

    var itemArray = document.trans.ItemNo; ???

sincein the formitsnameis ItemNo[]

Comment: I do not have any experience using document.trans, so I left that part out. I will update my answer with some jQuery to retrieve the select option values.

Comment: Oops, that parseInt should be a parseFloat in case your sale price as a decimal value. Will update that as well.

Comment: What *is* `document.trans`? It's something I've not come across before... =/

Comment: well its like document.[formID].[elementname] . all referring to the form.useful when there are multiple forms in a page.
i used this in my checker like document.trans.ItemCategory.value.match("Watch") {function here}...
well it wast in my code bit i started my form like <form id="trans" ..... >  
sorry for the late response i thought it would update instantly 

can you reallyplease helpany waytoaccessthe value. itstill wontwork

Comment: The above didn't work? Were you able to debug it at all? Since you're already using jQuery, I would let jQuery do the work for you so you don't have to have such lengthy statements.

Comment: Oops. When I changed `this.value.split(':');` to `this.val().split(':');` I forgot to add `$()` around `this` since .val() is a jQuery function. I have updated my answer again. Sorry about that!